# List appointments in Outlook by date using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to list(Extract) the Outlook Appointments by Date by using C#. I used restrict method to do that,

```
  sSearch = "[Start] >= ' " + startDate + " ' and [Start] <= ' " + endDate + " '";
```

But, if the day after End Date(endDate) has a All Day appointment it is also listed. How to overcome from this problem ????

Comment: yappa, please see my answer below. this would get you going and also please visit the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg619398(v=office.14).aspx

```
 private void DemoAppointmentsInRange()
{
    Outlook.Folder calFolder =
        Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
        as Outlook.Folder;
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end = start.AddDays(5);
    Outlook.Items rangeAppts = GetAppointmentsInRange(calFolder, start, end);
    if (rangeAppts != null)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in rangeAppts)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Subject: " + appt.Subject 
                + " Start: " + appt.Start.ToString("g"));
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get recurring appointments in date range.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder"></param>
/// <param name="startTime"></param>
/// <param name="endTime"></param>
/// <returns>Outlook.Items</returns>
private Outlook.Items GetAppointmentsInRange(
    Outlook.Folder folder, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    string filter = "[Start] >= '"
        + startTime.ToString("g")
        + "' AND [End] <= '"
        + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";
    Debug.WriteLine(filter);
    try
    {
        Outlook.Items calItems = folder.Items;
        calItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        calItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
        Outlook.Items restrictItems = calItems.Restrict(filter);
        if (restrictItems.Count > 0)
        {
            return restrictItems;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Comment: play with the end date time stamp, thats likely causing the issue

Comment: string filter = "[Start] <= '"
    + endTime.ToString("g")
    + "' AND [End] >= '"
    + startTime.ToString("g") + "'";

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Tam Tam's. Just a little less code. I spent all day looking for a basic sample I could use in LinqPad. This is what I ended up with.

```
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Application a = new Application();
Items i = a.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items;
i.IncludeRecurrences = true;
i.Sort("[Start]");
i = i.Restrict("[Start] >= '10/1/2013' AND [End] <= '10/2/2013'");
var r =
    from ai in i.Cast<AppointmentItem>()
    select new {ai.Start,ai.Duration,ai.Subject};
r.Dump();
```

Comment: Nice!  I love linqpad!